# Corona SDK - Resize a moving physics body

Tags: lua, box2d, coronasdk

I've been trying to create a simple game where the player controls a physics body that increases in size when it collides with other objects. From what I understand it's not possible to scale the actual physics body directly, instead I'm trying to create a new one using the parameters of the original one. However, when created a new physics body of the appropriate size has been created, I lose the ability to move it around. Any form of input would be highly appriciated, as I can't figure out what to do (I'm still very new to this).
Here's what I've got so far:

```
function movePlayer(event)

if "began" == event.phase then
    player.isFocus = true

    player.x0 = event.x - player.x
    player.y0 = event.y - player.y
elseif player.isFocus == true then
    if "moved" == event.phase then
        player.x = event.x - player.x0
        player.y = event.y - player.y0
        stayOnScreen( player )
    elseif "ended" == phase or "cancelled" == phase then
        player.isFocus = false
    end
end

return true
end


function checks()

if player.resize == true then
    local player2 = createPlayer(player.x, player.y, player.xScale, player.yScale, player.rotation)

    if player.isFocus == true then
        player2.isFocus = player.isFocus
        player2.x0 = player.x0
        player2.y0 = player.y0
    end
    player2.resize = false
    player:removeSelf()
    player = player2
end 
end

player:addEventListener("touch", movePlayer)
Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", checks)
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Here's the code that generates a new player and adds a physics body:

```
function createPlayer( x, y, xScale, yScale, rotation)
local player = display.newImageRect("images/p1.png", 71, 71)
player.x = x
player.y = y
player.xScale = xScale
player.yScale = yScale

local playerCollisionFilter = { categoryBits = 2, maskBits = 5 }
local playerBodyElement = { filter=playerCollisionFilter, radius = (player.xScale * (player.width *0.5)) }


player.objectType = "player"
physics.addBody ( player, "dynamic", playerBodyElement )
player.isBullet = true
player.isSleepingAllowed = false
player.rotation = rotation
player.resize = false

return player
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem with your "touch" event handler to me. Specifically, this line:

```
player:addEventListener("touch", movePlayer)
```

is only executed once, when the main Lua file is load. That handler needs to be removed from ***player*** and added to ***player2*** when you're making the change to ***player2*** in the `checks()` function.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! I just added the creation of the handler to the createPlayer function and it worked like a charm! Once again, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

After you do player:removeSelf(), the physics engine will no longer have a reference to player (because the removeSelf also unregisters from physics). So you have to make player (player2) a physics body:

```
physics.addBody(player2, ...)
```

where `...` represents same parameters as used when you added player the first time.

*Update:*

OK so you've already taken care of addBody. I can't see any obvious problem with your code, but you are using the same var name "player" in a few places so its hard to be sure. Try using `event.target` instead of `player` in handler, see if that helps. For maintainability consider naming the locals like newPlayer, a give unique name for the global like rocket or person whatever your player actually is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, player two is made into a physics body upon creation (I added the code that creates a new player).

Comment: Ok I'll try that.
I'll also try to give the variables more unique names in the future, thanks for the tip!